# How to Get Calendar Event global status?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

This is concerning Google script to access Calendar event info

I'm looking for a method to get a Calendar Event global status? like for a Calendar Event with as status of attendess:
10 guests ==> 4 Yes, 3 MayBe, 1 No, 2 Awaiting

I've searched but I find only the way to get the status by guest, then implement a code to count individualy the global status.

Is there a way to get directly the global status?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to have written a function that does this. Here's an example of usage:

```
var summary = guestSummary(event.getGuestList());
Logger.log(summary);
...

[13-06-26 22:39:58:253 EDT] {respondedMaybe=0.0, awaiting=0.0, additional=0.0, respondedNo=0.0, respondedYes=1.0, invited=1.0}
```

I elected to use the guest list as a parameter, in order to support both CalendarEvent and CalendarEventSeries.

```
/**
 * Return an object enumerating guest list summary information.
 *
 * @param {EventGuest[]} guestlist Array of EventGuests.
 *
 * @returns {object} guest list summary
 */
function guestSummary( guestlist ) {
  var invited = guestlist.length;
  var respondedYes = 0;
  var respondedMaybe = 0;
  var respondedNo = 0;
  var awaiting = 0;
  var additional = 0;
  guestlist.forEach( function (guest) {
    switch (guest.getGuestStatus()) {
      case CalendarApp.GuestStatus.INVITED:
        awaiting++;
        break;
      case CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES:
        respondedYes++;
        break;
      case CalendarApp.GuestStatus.NO:
        respondedNo++;
        break;
      case CalendarApp.GuestStatus.MAYBE:
        respondedMaybe++;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    additional += guest.getAdditionalGuests();
  });
  return {
    invited : invited,
    respondedYes : respondedYes,
    respondedMaybe : respondedMaybe,
    respondedNo : respondedNo,
    awaiting : awaiting,
    additional : additional
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this finlay what I did, I guess this should be added by Google as a direct Calendar Event Attrribute. Thanks @Mogsdad